# DAX - Complex Rolling Average

Tags: statistics, powerbi, dax

In its simplest form, I am trying to achieve a 12 Month Rolling average of "Active Assets"/"Number of Incidents".

The desired calculation is much easier to explain in Excel form:

```
Year    Month     |  Average # Equipment  | Total Incidents
2018    January            100                    6
2018    February           101                    8
2018    March              101                    7
.................        ........             ........

Calculation = SUM(C2:C14)/SUM(D2:D14)
```

Relevant Power BI data is in two tables - 'Data - Assets' and 'Data - WO'.

Each incident has a "DateIssued" and each Asset has a "CommissionDate" and "DecommissionDate".

I should count Assets only when the date in question is between the Commission and Decommission dates, and only count the incidents for Assets that are currently active (between the dates).

Below is my closest attempt so far. However, it is portrayed in a 365 day time frame rather than a 12 month. Also, it does not sum the Asset count as is required from the desired calculation.

```
Calculation =
CALCULATE (
    IF (
        COUNT ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) >= 365,
        COUNTROWS ( 'Data - Assets' ) / COUNT ( 'Data - WO'[ID] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'DateTable'[Date] ),
        'DateTable'[Date]
            > ( MAX ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) - 365 )
            && 'DateTable'[Date] <= MAX ( 'DateTable'[Date] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Data - Assets' ),
        (
            'Data - Assets'[CommissionDate] <= MAX ( DateTable[Date] )
                || ISBLANK ( 'Data - Assets'[CommissionDate] )
        )
            && (
                'Data - Assets'[DecommissionDate] >= MAX ( 'DateTable'[Date] )
                    || ISBLANK ( 'Data - Assets'[DecommissionDate] )
            )
    )
)
```

Am I on the right track here at all? New to DAX and any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the field 'DateTable'[Date] going to be used as a slicer? To reframe, is the rolling 12 month average based on the field 'DateTable'[Date]?

Comment: Yes, my visuals utilize 'DateTable'[Date] to alter the display to look at dates in question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing a complex measure calculation, I like to split the calculation so that its easier to manipulate. You can use something similar to below:

```
Count = IF(Data[CommissionDate]>=DATEADD(DateTable[Date],-12,MONTH)&&Data[DeCommissionDate]<=DATEADD(DateTable[Date]),1,0)
Assets1 = IF(Data[CommissionDate]>=DATEADD(DateTable[Date],-12,MONTH)&&Data[DeCommissionDate]<=DATEADD(DateTable[Date]),Data[Assets],0)
12MonthCalc = SUM(Data[Assets1])/SUM(Data[Count])
```

You can replace the date condition with your exact specifics and you should have the solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the [Count] measure. I believe I found an error in the second DATEADD function. Despite this, this syntax does not let me use a column reference [CommissionDate] and [DecommissionDate].

Should this instead be a column in the 'Data - Assets' table? If so, how does this work?

Comment: The columns I have used won't exactly match the column names in your table. You will have to replace these column names with the columns from your table. Data is the name of the table as per the above formula. To replace the column names, delete the column in the formula and start typing commissiondate, it should give you suggestions regarding the actual column name

Comment: Essentially the formula for Count is: Count = IF({Your Commision Date Field}>=DATEADD({Your Date Field},-12,MONTH)&&{You Decommission Date field}<=DATEADD({Your Date Field}),1,0)

Comment: Anything within the braces {} should be replace by the corresponding fields